# C++ VS needs to recompile after changing project directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This happens to me every time when I change the directory (change the name of main folder) of my C++ project, VS seems to need to recompile the whole thing, which in my case is 10 minutes.

Is this how it is or is there a way to improve this situation?

I'm using VS 2015 Update 3. In my project I'm using Qt 5.8.0 and several other libraries (i.e: boost)

Comment: Are you really changing the name of folders that often? Just curious, if yes why?

Comment: For this application to execute it needs several hundreds of MB of dlls in the same folder as the executable file (debug). I'm copying the source code (<1MB) and changing the name of the current folder each time I want to make a backup.

Comment: @Sturm: You may want to read about Git. Also, rename the backup, not your working dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not* recompiling is an optimization, and Visual Studio plays it safe. If the optimization is suspect, it's not done. Debugging an executable which doesn't match your code can cost way more time than those 10 minutes.

That said, I agree wuth Rakete1111's comment. It probably could be made to work, but why?